# Linkedin link preview in message show error for website

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I am sending a link in my LinkedIn messages to customers. When ever I share the link the issue is shown as "How to enable Javascript"

[image: Linkedin message]

Can someone guide, as to what might be wrong here. May be some tag missing on the website. The website is http://www.yangpoo.com/

Comment: meta tags might not be set properly

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming. See: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/3082296).

Comment: @priyanshisrivastava thanks for the hint. Meta tags were missing in the website.

Comment: @Godwin updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The  tag provides **metadata about the HTML document**. Metadata will not be displayed on the page but will be machine or browser parsable.

So in order to get expected fetching of your site link while sharing..metadata plays a very important role. You need to set metadata of name, image, and link property mainly